# Ruby regex: ignore quotes if a colon stands before them

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to write a Ruby regex which would capture quoted phrases apart from the ones which have ":" just before them. For example:

> Obama: "Yes, we can!"

Should be ignored.

I wrote some tests:

http://rubular.com/r/OJmkLd68gc

Comment: Plus 1 for the perfect way to ask a regex question... examples, link, and clear instructions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: Yet more tweaking.

Depending on precisely what the input looks like, this works for ASCII:

```
 (?<! [:\s] ) \s* ( ["'] ) (?: (?! \1 ) . )+ \1
```

For “Unicode ‘matching’ quotes”, you have to be a bit more ‹specific› in your pairings, perhaps along these lines:

```
(?xs) (?<!:) \s+ 
  (?: ( ["'] ) (?: (?! \1 ) . )+ \1
    | “ .*? ”    # English etc
    | ‘ .*? ’   
    | « .*? »    # French, Spanish, Italian
    | ‹ .*? ›
    | „ .*? “    # German, Icelandic, Romanian
    | ‚ .*? ‘
    | „ .?* ”    # Hungarian
    | ” .?* ”    # Swedish
    | ’ .?* ’    
    | » .?* «    # Danish, Hungarian
    | › .*? ‹
    | 「 .*? 」   # Japanese, Chinese
    | 『 .?* 』  
  )
```

You can read more about the sorts of paired quotation marks used by various languages [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks).

Here’s a test program in Perl, but the principles should hold perfectly well in Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use open qw[ :std IO :utf8 ];
while (<DATA>) {
    print if / (?<! [:\s] ) \s* ( ["'] ) (?: (?! \1 ) . )+ \1/sx;
}
__END__
"Take off, hoser!"
Dorothy Parker:Brevity is the soul of lingerie.
Dorothy Parker:"Brevity is the soul of lingerie."
Dorothy Parker: "Brevity is the soul of lingerie."
Dorothy Parker:  "Brevity is the soul of lingerie."
Larry Wall: I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)
Larry Wall said, "I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)"
Larry Wall said: “I don't know if it's what you want, but it’s what you get. :-)”
Larry Wall said:   “I don't know if it's what you want, but it’s what you get. :-)”
Larry Wall said, “I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)”
Boss: And what's that "goto" doing there?!?
Hacker: Er, I guess my finger slipped when I was typing "getservbyport"...
‘Nevermore!’ quoth the raven.
Quoth the raven: ‘Nevermore!’
'I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic,' he said, and fell silent.
src/perl/mg.c: "I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic," he said, and fell silent.
src/perl/mg.c: 'I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic,' he said, and fell silent.
src/perl/mg.c => "I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic,' he said, and fell silent."
‘I wish I had never come here, and I don’t want to see no more magic,’ he said, and fell silent.’
“I wish I had never come here, and I don’t want to see no more magic,’ he said, and fell silent.”
```

The output is

```
"Take off, hoser!"
Larry Wall: I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)
Larry Wall said, "I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)"
Larry Wall said: “I don't know if it's what you want, but it’s what you get. :-)”
Larry Wall said:   “I don't know if it's what you want, but it’s what you get. :-)”
Larry Wall said, “I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)”
Boss: And what's that "goto" doing there?!?
Hacker: Er, I guess my finger slipped when I was typing "getservbyport"...
'I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic,' he said, and fell silent.
src/perl/mg.c: 'I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic,' he said, and fell silent.
src/perl/mg.c => "I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic,' he said, and fell silent."
```

That probably looks “wrong”, but it’s because of the internal quotes.  Here is a more complete version which better illustrates the issues:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use open qw[ :std IO :utf8 ];
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;    
    my $bingo = m{
        (?<! [:\s] ) \s*
        (?: (?<= ^  )
          | (?<= \s )
        )
        (?: ( ["'] ) (?: (?! \1 ) . )+ \1
          | “ .*? ”    # English etc
          | ‘ .*? ’
        )
    }sx;

    if ($bingo) {
        printf("Line %2d, quote 「%s」\n",   $., $&);
        printf(" " x 7 . "in line 『%s』\n", $_);
    } else {
        printf("Line %2d IGNORE 『%s』\n", $., $_);
    }    
}    
__END__
"Take off, hoser!"
Dorothy Parker:Brevity is the soul of lingerie.
Dorothy Parker:"Brevity is the soul of lingerie."
Dorothy Parker: "Brevity is the soul of lingerie."
Dorothy Parker:  "Brevity is the soul of lingerie."
Larry Wall: I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)
Larry Wall said, "I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)"
Larry Wall said: “I don't know if it's what you want, but it’s what you get. :-)”
Larry Wall said:   “I don't know if it's what you want, but it’s what you get. :-)”
Larry Wall said, “I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)”
Boss: And what's that "goto" doing there?!?
Hacker: Er, I guess my finger slipped when I was typing "getservbyport"...
‘Nevermore!’ quoth the raven.
Quoth the raven: ‘Nevermore!’
'I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic,' he said, and fell silent.
src/perl/mg.c: "I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic," he said, and fell silent.
src/perl/mg.c: 'I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic,' he said, and fell silent.
src/perl/mg.c => "I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic,' he said, and fell silent."
‘I wish I had never come here, and I don’t want to see no more magic,’ he said, and fell silent.’
“I wish I had never come here, and I don’t want to see no more magic,’ he said, and fell silent.”
```

Whose output is:

```
Line  1, quote 「"Take off, hoser!"」
       in line 『"Take off, hoser!"』
Line  2 IGNORE 『Dorothy Parker:Brevity is the soul of lingerie.』
Line  3 IGNORE 『Dorothy Parker:"Brevity is the soul of lingerie."』
Line  4 IGNORE 『Dorothy Parker: "Brevity is the soul of lingerie."』
Line  5 IGNORE 『Dorothy Parker:  "Brevity is the soul of lingerie."』
Line  6 IGNORE 『Larry Wall: I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)』
Line  7, quote 「 "I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)"」
       in line 『Larry Wall said, "I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)"』
Line  8 IGNORE 『Larry Wall said: “I don't know if it's what you want, but it’s what you get. :-)”』
Line  9 IGNORE 『Larry Wall said:   “I don't know if it's what you want, but it’s what you get. :-)”』
Line 10, quote 「 “I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)”」
       in line 『Larry Wall said, “I don't know if it's what you want, but it's what you get. :-)”』
Line 11, quote 「 "goto"」
       in line 『Boss: And what's that "goto" doing there?!?』
Line 12, quote 「 "getservbyport"」
       in line 『Hacker: Er, I guess my finger slipped when I was typing "getservbyport"...』
Line 13, quote 「‘Nevermore!’」
       in line 『‘Nevermore!’ quoth the raven.』
Line 14 IGNORE 『Quoth the raven: ‘Nevermore!’』
Line 15, quote 「'I wish I had never come here, and I don'」
       in line 『'I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic,' he said, and fell silent.』
Line 16 IGNORE 『src/perl/mg.c: "I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic," he said, and fell silent.』
Line 17 IGNORE 『src/perl/mg.c: 'I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic,' he said, and fell silent.』
Line 18, quote 「 "I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic,' he said, and fell silent."」
       in line 『src/perl/mg.c => "I wish I had never come here, and I don't want to see no more magic,' he said, and fell silent."』
Line 19, quote 「‘I wish I had never come here, and I don’」
       in line 『‘I wish I had never come here, and I don’t want to see no more magic,’ he said, and fell silent.’』
Line 20, quote 「“I wish I had never come here, and I don’t want to see no more magic,’ he said, and fell silent.”」
       in line 『“I wish I had never come here, and I don’t want to see no more magic,’ he said, and fell silent.”』
```

Also, there is a standard Unicode derived property called `\p{Quotation_Mark}` or `\p{QMark}` for short, but Ruby doesn’t support it. You may list these all out using [the *unichars* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars):

```
$ unichars '\p{qmark}'
 "    34 0022 QUOTATION MARK
 '    39 0027 APOSTROPHE
 «   171 00AB LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
 »   187 00BB RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
 ‘  8216 2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
 ’  8217 2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
 ‚  8218 201A SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
 ‛  8219 201B SINGLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK
 “  8220 201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
 ”  8221 201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
 „  8222 201E DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
 ‟  8223 201F DOUBLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK
 ‹  8249 2039 SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
 ›  8250 203A SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
 「 12300 300C LEFT CORNER BRACKET
 」 12301 300D RIGHT CORNER BRACKET
 『 12302 300E LEFT WHITE CORNER BRACKET
 』 12303 300F RIGHT WHITE CORNER BRACKET
 〝 12317 301D REVERSED DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK
 〞 12318 301E DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK
 〟 12319 301F LOW DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK
 ﹁ 65089 FE41 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT CORNER BRACKET
 ﹂ 65090 FE42 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT CORNER BRACKET
 ﹃ 65091 FE43 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT WHITE CORNER BRACKET
 ﹄ 65092 FE44 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT WHITE CORNER BRACKET
 ＂ 65282 FF02 FULLWIDTH QUOTATION MARK
 ＇ 65287 FF07 FULLWIDTH APOSTROPHE
 ｢ 65378 FF62 HALFWIDTH LEFT CORNER BRACKET
 ｣ 65379 FF63 HALFWIDTH RIGHT CORNER BRACKET
```

You can list out all of a code point’s properties using [the *uniprops* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniprops):

```
$ uniprops -a 2018
U+2018 ‹‘› \N{ LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK }:
    \pP \p{Pi}
    All Any Assigned InGeneralPunctuation Case_Ignorable CI Common Zyyy Pi P General_Punctuation Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Initial_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn Print Punctuation QMark Quotation_Mark X_POSIX_Graph X_POSIX_Print X_POSIX_Punct
    Age=1.1 Bidi_Class=ON Bidi_Class=Other_Neutral BC=ON Block=General_Punctuation Canonical_Combining_Class=0 Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered CCC=NR Canonical_Combining_Class=NR Script=Common Decomposition_Type=None DT=None East_Asian_Width=A East_Asian_Width=Ambiguous EA=A Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other GCB=XX Grapheme_Cluster_Break=XX Hangul_Syllable_Type=NA Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable HST=NA Joining_Group=No_Joining_Group JG=NoJoiningGroup Joining_Type=Non_Joining JT=U Joining_Type=U Line_Break=QU Line_Break=Quotation LB=QU Numeric_Type=None NT=None Numeric_Value=NaN NV=NaN Present_In=1.1 IN=1.1 Present_In=2.0 IN=2.0 Present_In=2.1 IN=2.1 Present_In=3.0 IN=3.0 Present_In=3.1 IN=3.1 Present_In=3.2 IN=3.2 Present_In=4.0 IN=4.0 Present_In=4.1 IN=4.1 Present_In=5.0 IN=5.0 Present_In=5.1 IN=5.1 Present_In=5.2 IN=5.2 Present_In=6.0 IN=6.0 SC=Zyyy Script=Zyyy Sentence_Break=CL Sentence_Break=Close SB=CL Word_Break=MB Word_Break=MidNumLet WB=MB _Case_Ignorable _X_Begin
```

Comment: The OP wants quoted strings *that do not have* colons before them. Also, that should probably be `(?:(?!\1).)+` `:)`

Comment: Actually, not quite `:)` if you have more than one space, it can match starting from the second (because the first one isn't a colon). Also, `\s+` requires at least one space, but that one is easy. Interesting quotes though...

Comment: @Kobi: Arg, you’re right. I found another problem-case, too: What happens when you start with a quote right at the start?  And do you have to have whitespace? I’ve added an example test suite. Depending on what you really want, you probably want to alter the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go I  think http://rubular.com/r/hFylsgU3OT

```
 ^[^:]*"(.*?)"$
```

This BTW is the perfect way to ask a regex question... examples, link, and clear instructions

Comment: Thanks, but I realized, that I forgot one test: the text should not be captured only if the colon is just before the quotes (something like :[\s*]): http://rubular.com/r/NtbcgGqX4h